# Laravel session across subdomains

Tags: php, session, cookies, laravel, subdomain

I have a marketing application that is on the main domain (www.example.com ), and an admin application that is on the subdomain(accounts.example.com ). A user would visit www.example.com , register/login and gets redirected to accounts.example.com.  My problem is that my session cookie from www.example.com  is being overwritten when a user is redirected to accounts.example.com.

Both applications are using the same session cookie, but the accounts application always overwrites it. My data that was set for the session is no longer available after being redirected to the subdomain (unavailable in both domains). Anyone have an idea how I can approach this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Web servers usually do not permit session data to be shared across domains, or even sub domains. For that purpose, you must store the session data in a place where it can be reached across domains... e.g. a database.